# Series convergence for every real number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

We have the sequence $$x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(2\alpha)^i}{4^i+(\alpha^2)^i}$$ and we have to prove that it is convergent $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. If we use the Absolute Convergence Theorem, we only have to prove it for $\alpha \gt 0$. The sequence is clearly monotonous increasing, so how can I find an upper bound?

Comment: It does **not** converge for all values of $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: Take $\displaystyle a=\alpha^i,b=2^i$ then 

$\displaystyle\frac{(2\alpha)^i}{4^i+(\alpha^2)^i}=\dfrac{ab}{a^2+b^2}=\frac12\dfrac{2ab}{a^2+b^2} \leq\frac12$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\left|\frac{(2\alpha)^i}{4^i+\alpha^{2i}}\right|\le \left|\frac{(2\alpha)^i}{4^i}\right|$$

and

$$\left|\frac{(2\alpha)^i}{4^i+\alpha^{2i}}\right|\le \left|\frac{(2\alpha)^i}{\alpha^{2i}}\right|$$

But what happens when $|\alpha|=2$?

Comment: I got it, thanks! The last case doesn't work, maybe it was a mistake.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.